# C Chess game - Letters not showing correctly on black part of the board

Tags: c, chess

I am building a chess game in C and I am having a problem on showing the letters on the black side of the board. On the white side of the board it's working as expected.
You can see the problem here:
Here is the code I have so far:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Matriz de 8 por 8 para fazer os quadrados do jogo
char xadrez[8][8] = {
    { 'T', 'C', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'C', 'T'}, //Pretas em maiúsculas
    { 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P'},
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    { 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'},//Brancas em minúsculas
    { 't', 'c', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'c', 't'}

};

// Função para pintar a tela e o texto dentro dos quadrados
int pintarTelaTexto() {
    system("CLS");// verificar para que serve system cls
    //linha - coluna e r para controle da casa central onde vamos por a letra
    int lin, col, r;

    for (lin=0; lin < 8; lin++) {

        for (r=0; r < 3; r++) {
            for (col=0; col < 8; col++) {
                //char letra com problema nao aparece na casa central apa

                char peca = xadrez[lin][col];
                char letra = ((lin + col) % 2 == 0) ? '\xB2' : ' ';
                letra = (r == 1 && peca != ' ') ? peca : letra; // operador ternário
                    if ((lin + col ) % 2 == 0) {
                        printf("\xB2\xB2%c\xB2\xB2", letra);
                    }
                    else {
                        // %c para inserção da letra
                        printf("  %c  "), letra;
                    }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    pintarTelaTexto();
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is `'\xb2'` supposed to do? Turn the background colour white? Or black? And what is the foreground colour (the colour of the text)? If you try to print black text on black background, that won't work very well now, would it?

Comment: The code does not compile `printf("  %c  "), letra;` also remember to `#include <conio.h>` which declares the function `getch`.

Comment: One may want to instantiate different pieces with different behaviours instead of doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! It's printing white letters on black screen. The letters do appear but actually not the right letters. \xb2 is making the very small white squares that build the each square.  I will add conio.h as well Weather Vane!

Comment: @WeatherVane Well that's just using the bog-standard comma operator. Doesn't do anything useful and leads to UB since no argument is passes for the format, but it does compile. :)

Comment: Yes it's compiling and doing everything expected so far on half of the squares on the board. On the other half it's always printing a random letter. Trying to find out why it's doing that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I meant: not compiling cleanly, and of no use.

Comment: @DianaMoura does "some random letter" come from the mistaken `printf(" %c "), letra;`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Well yes, the %c is supossed to call in the letra / letter but it's calling a random letter everywhere instead of the right letter for each case. Funny thing is it's assumed correctly on the white squares. See this image https://imgur.com/o0iK8Ly

Comment: @DianaMoura See mine and WeatherWanes little discussion in the comments. Is `letra` an argument to `printf`? Is it *really*? Doesn't the compiler give you any warnings? If not then you need to enable more warnings, and maybe even treat them as errors.

Comment: You mean there is something wrong with letra/letter but actually it's working for the other white  squares. That's what I am not getting.

Comment: Compare: Your `printf("  %c  "), letra;` versus the correct `printf("  %c  ", letra);`

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude :D only now I understood. So stupid of me! :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Answered by @Someprogrammerdude

Compare: Your printf(" %c "), letra; versus the correct printf(" %c ", letra);